# Syntax for matching a directory and then entering it to finish out the script

Tags: sh

newbie here so I hope I'll find some help :)

Trying basic Python programming and looking for some help on this one...

Anyone care to look over my code and tell me why it's not changing directory?  It will match my statement and echo correctly but won't go into the directory so I can execute the next part.

Really just looking for a way to do a directory search first and match it against a wildcard.  Syntax is giving me headache.

Thanks

```
read -e -p "Enter the name of the Program to Backup/Erase : " program
rm /usr/local/bin/"${program}"transfer
rm /usr/local/bin/"${program}"file
rm -r ~/Saved/"${program}"

if [ -d "~/."${program}"" ]; then
echo "Using Default Name!"&cd ~/."${program}"

elif [ -d "~/."${program}"core" ]; then
echo "Found Core Directory!"&cd ~/."${program}"core

elif -d ~/."${program}"chain; then
echo "Found Chain Directory!"&cd ~/."${program}"chain

fi
```

Comment: None of this is Python :) It's all sh. I think you need two ampersands rather than one before the cd.

Comment: I added the double && and same issue.  It never changes to the matching directory.  Perhaps a different command to achieve my needs?  Yes looks like SH ;)

Comment: Whenever you have a shell script problem error, a good first step is to cut and paste your code into
[shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/)
and correct the errors (important) and warnings (might be important) that it identifies. If you have trouble understanding its messages or the problem persists, then come here and ask a more specific question.

Comment: very helpful site for syntax errors thank you!

I think I was able to get it working by ignoring the CD and just having the command execute with full path.  *cross fingers

Answer (score 1):

I think I found your problem.
This isn't Python programming your using (it's shell programming) and there are many syntax errors in the script.

Line 6, 9, and 12 have the same problem:

- `if [ -d "~/."${program}"" ]; then` should be
  `if [ -d "~/.${program}" ]; then`
- `elif [ -d "~/."${program}"core" ]; then` should be 
  `elif [ -d "~/.${program}core" ]; then`
- `elif -d ~/."${program}"chain; then` should be 
  `elif [ -d "~/.${program}chain" ]; then`

Line 7, 10, and 13 also share a problem:

- `echo "Using Default Name!"&cd ~/.${program}` should be 
  `echo "Using Default Name!" && cd ~/.${program}`
- `echo "Found Core Directory!"&cd ~/.${program}core` should be 
  `echo "Found Core Directory!" && cd ~/.${program}core`
- `echo "Found Chain Directory!"&cd ~/.${program}chain` should be 
  `echo "Found Chain Directory!" && cd ~/.${program}chain`

Also make sure you run this program as root 
(you might not have sufficent rights to remove files from `/usr/local/bin`):

Add this as the first line of your script:

```
[ $UID -ne 0 ] && echo "You must be root," && exit 1
```

You should be able to see the expected results now.